# JQueryUI: Best way to create two drag/drop lists where one is a Sortable, the other re-sorts on the drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following scenario.  I have a long list of columns, which are represented by `<li>` objects in two specific `<ul>` lists.  On the left-side, are all of the fields which can be selected by a user.  On the right-side, is where the user drag and drops any fields they want from the left.  Essentially, this scenario is used to build an ordered list of columns for a dynamic report.

Using the JQueryUI `Sortable()` method, I've easily created  lists that are used for dragging and dropping these column `<li>` elements as desired.  Everything works perfectly when dragging contents from the left list, to the right because I want my users to be able to order the columns for their report.

However, if the user drags an item from the right list to the left, (say, they decided to NOT include a column that added earlier) I want to add the item back to the left-side `Sortable()` list but I want it to be placed in a specific, pre-ordered position, and not below the element which the column was dropped on.

What's the best approach to this need?  Should I use a JQueryUI `Sortable()` object for my left-side column container, and resort the data as it's dropped, or is there a better JQuery tool for the job?  If I should define my left-side list as a `Sortable()` object, how should I modify it as to re-order the list properly after the drop operation has completed?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/1609/) which I used for the basic mechanics of these lists.  Again, the right-side list is behaving as I desire.  However, I want the left hand side to always be sorted based of a value used for forced sorting.  For the case of this example, the left should always be sorted on the `data-sort` attribute defined on each `<li>`.

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question itself. BTW, do you wish the left list to still be sortable if item from left list is dropped still on left list? I mean, does the left list still has to be sortable?

Comment: No.  I want to force the left-side to maintain a specific order.

Comment: So like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/1610/  ?

Comment: When I get back to my desk, I'll try to embed my code into the post.

Comment: That's it.  Write an answer briefly explaining the modifications and you get the answer mark.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort all dropped items in `#left-list` depending specific `data-sort` attribute. You have to use `update` callback which is fired on each update, unlike `stop` one.

```js
$("#left-side").sortable({
  connectWith: "#right-side",
  update: function(e, info) {
    $(this).children('li').sort(function(a, b) {
        return +a.dataset.sort - +b.dataset.sort;
    }).appendTo(this);
  }
});
$("#right-side").sortable({
  connectWith: "#left-side"
});
// code to set relevant data-sort attribute for each LIs
$("#left-side, #right-side").find('li').attr('data-sort', function() {
  return $(this).index('body ul.ui-sortable li');
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid Black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
li {
  background-color: Azure;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click items to select them</h1>
<ul id="left-side">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="right-side">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five
  </li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks again.  This is the answer.